Forms overlay winLogon
I have a form in C# that does facial recognition, would it be possible to autologin as soon as it detects a face? (I already have the autologin function created).
I will make the Credential Provider and Forms code available (it's a simple form).
If you have any ideas I would appreciate it.
I got the ideia from here
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FaceRecognition;

namespace reconhecimentoFacialC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        FaceRec faceRec = new FaceRec();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            faceRec.openCamera(pictureBox1, pictureBox2);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            faceRec.Save_IMAGE(textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("save sucess");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           faceRec.isTrained = true;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

       
    }
}

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
   using System;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           var networkCredential = CredentialsDialog.GetCredentials("Hey!", "We would like a login.");

           if (networkCredential != null)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"Username: \'{networkCredential.UserName}\'");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("No credential detected.");
           }

           Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   } 
}

       }


Here is a small part of the Program.cs code, what would be the best way to override it?
I want the forms overlay this:


Andre, if you have 2 forms, open form1 (the one with text "Hey! we would like a login"). Then you open Form2 using .ShowDialog method. This form2 will be responsible for face recognition. Once the face is detected and recognized, form2 would fill data fields in form1 that is accessible since it is still opened, and then form2 would close, returning control to form1 (main credential form), that would now have datafields populated

Please don't use the answer feature to post comments

"You could try to open a form with .ShowDialog, " was meant to be the answer....

"Could try" is not an answer. How would this solve OP's issue? Please explain the answer. Furthermore an answer shouldn't request more clarifications, that's what comments are for

no, the black box in the background is the cmd , the photo in the POST is of the second code, where I have my credential provider connected, the first code is what I want to appear as an overlay, on top of it, I tried to create an executable of the first one to fill in the credentials and submit this executable appears, but it was not working as it appeared as a CD.
Any questions I am willing to answer, thank you

Please guys, I'm just trying to help ! I could not post comment to original question (<50 rep).

Andre, if you have 2 forms, open form1 (the one with text "Hey! we would like a login"). Then you open Form2 using .ShowDialog method. This form2 will be responsible for face recognition. Once the face is detected and recognized, form2 would fill data fields in form1 that is accessible since it is still opened, and then form2 would close, returning control to form1 (main credential form), that would now have datafields populated.

This is not a forum, it's a Q&A website. Please have a look at [answer] and this article

okk thank u Mario , and sorry for the inconvenient, im gonna try.

@DarkBee we understand,  I apologize for what happened, we gonna change it
